# Why does my cat attack everyone?

Tags: cats, behavior, biting

I've had a cat for about three years and ever since it was a kitten it would always bite me and other guests whenever they try to pet it. It only gets along with my brother and my brother doesn't even like cats. It's quite rude to me and will only rub against me when it is hungry, but whilst I'm giving it food it will headbutt me aggressively to push me out of the way and often wakes me up in the middle of the night for no reason other than to attack me.

My cat is also very prone to fighting with other cats during the day. It is rarely at home unless it is hungry and often comes back with cuts and blood on her from the other cats. She also fights the other pets in the house and I am constantly pulling claws out of the dog's nose from her. Even though she wasn't there first, she feels as though she has more authority than everyone else. Is something wrong with her?

Comment: is your cat neutered/spayed,some cats can be very territorial specially if they are not spayed/neutered and your cat is an oudoor cat so it do have the need to protect its own area.

Comment: @trondhansen Yes, my cat was neutered before I bought her. She was originally someone else's cat before she was mine and lived with them for a about a week or so until they gave her up.

Comment: if the cat is neutered it is a bit strange that it is still getting into fights with other cats.what do your vet have to say about this. i had a feral male cat and when i was at my vet to get him neutered the vet told me only one of the testicles was visible so he had to do surgery to find the one missing,is this problem possible in your cat? have the vet overlooked this when the cat was neutered.

Comment: @trondhansen When my cat was neutered it kept taking out its stitches and was bleeding everywhere but the vet said it was fine and kept stitching it back up. Do you think this is a problem? Should I take her back to get it checked?

Comment: you say the cat was neutered male cats get neutered and female cats get spayed.if your cat is female it will normaly not get into a fight so this is not normal behaviour,it is not very often neutered males gets into fights so it is not normal even for them.comments are not for long conversations so i need to stop now,when you get some more points we can take this on chat in the litterbox.

Comment: For your dogs sake, look into kitty claw caps. They are humane claw-sheaths that help the cat to retain natural claw function, but greatly mitigate damage.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be play aggression? They are often confused for each other. Try getting a toy and getting all the aggressive behaviour out by playing with a toy. Play until she's really tired. Do this everyday. Also one of my cats gets over stimulated when I pat his back. He will bite me if I do it too much. I just pat his head now and lots of play time and he has stopped biting me.